# Pre Populating a PHP Dynamic Select Option with Stored Session Variable

Tags: php, mysql, phpquery, dynamicquery

Im scratching my head once again and need your help.

What I have is a form that submits to a second page, with sessions enabled, i am storing the name value 2 fields on the form and setting their value names in the session so that if a user returns to a page their Username will already be populated in the text field. I have this working ok ..

The second page i am storing

```
$_SESSION['captured_by'] = $_POST['captured_by'];
$_SESSION['prid'] = $_POST['prid'];
```

**HOWEVER..**

Where i am stuck is getting a select option that is populated from a query to have the same functionality, so that when a user returns to the page, the selected option which has been saved in the session will keep that selection in the box rather than having to select it again.

Here is what i have as follows:

Form Page:
This does work and does return the captured_by text when i return to the page

```
<fieldset><legend>Lesson Added By *</legend>
<p class="multiple">(Required - Logon ID)</p>
<input name="captured_by" maxlength="12" id="searchfield" type="text" value="<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['captured_by'])){print stripslashes($_SESSION['captured_by']);}
else{print "   ";} ?>">
</fieldset>
```

The problem code is this

```
<select id="searchfield" name="prid">

<?php
 $query = "SELECT project_name, project_id FROM ll_project ORDER BY project_name ASC;";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 echo '<option value="'.$row['project_id'].'">'.$row['project_name'].' | '.$row['project_id'].'</option>';
 }
?>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

I need to edit this last section so that it picks up the previously selected option value from the stored session value.

Hope someone can help?
Many Thanks.
Tazzy

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question, when a user select an option in your form, you want to save that option so that if they return to the page, the option is selected. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes if they select say a project Name from the list - the actual value is an ID Number. If they submit the form and go to the 'success' page, they want to come back to this initial page to add another submit against the same project. So thats why i want the previously selected option to remain when they return to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<select id="searchfield" name="prid">

<?php
 $query = "SELECT project_name, project_id FROM ll_project ORDER BY project_name ASC;";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 echo '<option value="'.$row['project_id'].'"'. ((isset($_SESSION['prid']) && !empty($_SESSION['prid']) && ($_SESSION['prid'] == $row['project_id'])) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') .'>'.$row['project_name'].' | '.$row['project_id'].'</option>';
 }
?>
</select>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, I will try this at some point today and let you know the outcome. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok Nikhil, This now works as far as when i return to the page, the last option in the list is selected rather than the one which was set previously.

Comment: Perfect Nikhil! 

I LOVE YOU! :P 
Thank you soo much! ***Virtual Hug***

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use ajax when someone change the selection.

```
$('select#searchfield').change(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'changeSession.php', // This is the url that will be requested
      data: {prid: $('select#searchfield').val()},
      success: function(html){ 
        // nothing really happens because you simply update your session 
      },
      dataType: 'html'
    });
});
```

Then in changeSession.php

```
if(isset($_GET['projectId']{
   $_SESSION['captured_by'] = $_POST['prid'];
}
```

That should do the job. You then add a condition when the form is generated and you add selected='selected' if $_SESSION['prid'] is not empty.